# only positive numbers in list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create a list of positive numbers using single line but it's not working for me. Need help

```
numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
```

My code :

```
newlist = [n if n>0 else pass for n in numbers]
```

why `else pass` is not working?

Comment: You don't need to use `else pass` to get the expected output.

Comment: @ZdaR normal if..else else pass is working as expected but why it's not happening in list comprehension

eg:
`
    numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
   for n in numbers:
       if n>0:
           print(n)
       else:
            pass
`

Comment: The interesting part is why list comprehensions won't support a no-op for `if`/`else`. Correcting the code to make it work is one thing, but it doesn't explain why the OP's code is a `SyntaxError` because of `pass`.

Comment: @roganjosh because it's not the `if/elif/else` statement. The OP evaluates a ternary operator expression at each iteration step and the operator has no `pass`. The  `if`-like statement in list comprehensions goes after the `for x in iterable` part and even then it has no explicit `pass` argument.

Comment: @EliKorvigo and that would be far more interesting and appropriate as an answer than one that makes a basic list comprehension (since the question is explicitly about why `else pass` doesn't work, and not "how do I make `if`/`else` work). If they change `pass` to `None` then there is no longer a `SyntaxError` so it's logical to wonder why you can't simply `pass`. You have my upvote if you write as an answer.

Comment: whats the actual output/error?  Nones?

Answer (score 8):

You nearly had it:

```
numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]

newlist = [n for n in numbers if n > 0]
```

**output:**

```
[34.6, 44.9, 68.3, 44.6, 12.7]
```

---

In case you needed an else, to replace negative numbers with None, for instance: *(this is not what you asked for, but I include it here for completeness)*

```
newlist = [n if n > 0 else None for n in numbers]
```

**output:**

```
[34.6, None, 44.9, 68.3, None, 44.6, 12.7]
```

---

Lastly, if you wanted to convert all numbers to positive, using `abs`:

```
numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]

newlist = [abs(n) for n in numbers]
```

**output:**

```
[34.6, 203.4, 44.9, 68.3, 12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
```

Comment: You may find http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ useful @Phani

Comment: @Reblochon my expected output is     [34.6, 44.9, 68.3, 44.6, 12.7]
one with `else None ` printing     [34.6, None, 44.9, 68.3, None, 44.6, 12.7]

Comment: yes, I know, the second comprehension was to illustrate the use of `else`. I thought it might be useful to group both constructs in one answer.