# How to take only positive values in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can take only positive values in a list in Python.

For example, if I have `A = [1, 2, 3]`, it should return `[1, 2, 3]`

If I have `A = [-1, 2, 3]`, it should return `[2, 3]`

if I have `A = [-1, -2]`, it should return `None`

Thank you very much!

Comment: `positives = [x for x in A if x >= 0]`

Comment: `A = [-1, 2, 3]
B = [val for val in A if val > 0]
print(B)`

Comment: Wouldn't removing all the negative values from a list just be an empty list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [only positive numbers in list comprehension in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251689/only-positive-numbers-in-list-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: It would be better to get an empty list than `None`, that way the result is always a list.

Comment: Please search you question well before asking!

Answer (score 9):

The following will work:

```
def pos(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x > 0] or None

pos([-1, 2, 3])
# [2, 3]
pos([-1, -2])
# None
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The operation is O(N), right? Is there any method that achieves the same with O(1)?

Comment: Yes, `O(N)`, and nope, any method would have to inspect all elements. If the data was sorted and you had a data structure that supported `O(1)` slicing, you could improve to `O(logN)` using bisect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  `newlist = filter(lambda a: a > 0, [1, 2, 3]) or None` or `[i for i in original_list if i > 0] or None`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a firm requirement on the `None` final output I'd use this:

```
result = [i for i in l if i > 0] or None
```

This way, if you end up with no elements it gives you `None` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. The operation is O(N), right? Is there any method that achieves the same with O(1)?

Comment: @JunJang - There's no way to filter a list without visiting each member of the list.  The implication that you could get O(1) would require that you could visit _any_ number of members of _any_ list of _any_ size in constant time.  That's not possible.